# Sequence of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

Given

$$\displaystyle \mathbb P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}},~~~\text{and}~~~\displaystyle \mathbb P(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$$ where in $\alpha>0$,  $n\geq1$.

How can I prove that $$X_n\rightarrow 0~~\text{in}~~~ \mathcal L^{1}$$

Also, how do I show that $$\displaystyle \limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty}X_n=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }\alpha \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{if }\alpha >1
\end{cases}$$

Thanks for any help.

---

Attempt: The sequence converges in probability to $0$ if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)=0$.

By Borel-Cantelli Lemma the sequence converges almost surely to 0 if and only if

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)<\infty$

Comment: To prove $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^1$, show that $\mathbb{E}(|X_n-0|)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, it's easy you need to show that
$$ \mathbb E \vert X_n - 0 \vert \longrightarrow 0.   $$
After, for $\alpha > 1$, we use Borel-Cantelli:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n = 1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac 1 {n^{\alpha}} < \infty   $$
to deduce that $\mathbb P(\lim \sup \{ X_n = 1 \}) = 0$ and so $ \lim \sup X_n =0$ a.s.
For the case $\alpha \leq 1$, we can also use Borel-Cantelli but we need the $X_n$'s to be independent and I don't think it is true otherwise.

Comment: so you are saying that it is false that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow+\infty}X_n=1$ for $\alpha \leq 1$? Can you help me understand why the $X_n$'s are not independent in this case? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: No I am saying it is true that $\lim \sup X_n = 1 $ if the $X_n$'s are independent. It is the second part of Borel-Cantelli: if the events $A_n$ are independent and 
$$ \sum_{n =1}^\infty \mathbb P(A_n) = \infty,  $$
then $\mathbb P( \lim \sup A_n) = 1$. Here $A_n$ is the event $ \{ X_n = 1 \}$.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thanks again.